How the example of quotient groups related to homological algebra?
I'm currently taking a modern algebra course and the professor gave me the following example:

Consider two types of group of order $4$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. It is known that they are not isomorphic. Write $\mathbb{Z}_4=G_1=\{1,c,c^2,c^3\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2=G_2=\{1,a,b,ab\}$, take $H_1=\{1,c^2\}\le G_1$ and $H_2=\{1,a\}\le G_2$, we have $H_1\cong H_2$ and $G_1/H_1\cong G_2/H_2$, however $G_1\not\cong G_2$.

The professor said something in homological algebra is related to such phenomenon, but he would not elaborate it in detail. I'm curious about what "homological algebra" is related here.

It is a question about short exact sequences $1\to A\to B\to C\to1$ and whether they such sequences "split." The map with $B=G_1$ doesn't split, the other does.

Splitting short exact sequences are the trivial short exact sequences, with $B\cong A\times C.$

As mentioned in other comment, I think your prof referred to short exact sequence. You can read about splitting short exact sequence of groups in this expository note of Prof. Conrad here: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/splittinggp.pdf. There are many similar examples.

This may also be alluding to the concept of central extensions and its connection to cohomology, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Central_extension

Here is a short crash course on the homological algebra behind this phenomenon.
You can consider all sequences of maps of groups $\xi : P \stackrel{i}\to G \stackrel{p}\to Q$ where $i$ is into, $p$ is onto and $p\circ i=0$. This is called an extension of $Q$ by $P$. It is a group $G$ with normal subgroup $P$ such that $G/P=Q$. In this sense, $Q$ is extended by adding a piece isomorphic to $Q$.
Two extensions $\xi$ and $\xi'$ are equivalent if there exists a map of groups $u : G\to G'$ such that $ui = i$ and $pu = p$ (so $u$ leaves $P$ fixed, and projects to the same thing). You can check that in this case $u$ is an isomorphism of groups.
We say that such an extension $\xi$ is trivial if it is isomorphic to an extension of the form $\xi : P\to P\rtimes_\varphi Q\to Q$ where the middle term is a semi-direct product of $P$ by $Q$ along with $\varphi : Q \to \mathrm{Aut}(P)$. Equivalence classes of extensions are written $H^2(Q,P)$.
When $P=Q=\mathbb Z/2$, which is basically the simplest situation you can consider, we can classify extensions by hand. First, there is the trivial extension $\xi_0:\mathbb Z/2\to \mathbb Z/2\times \mathbb Z/2\to \mathbb Z/2$, since the semidirect product will always be direct. As usual, there is at least one extension.
Second, it is clear that any middle $G$ in such a sequence will be of order four, so the other option is that $G=\mathbb Z/4$. Up to isomorphism, there is a unique subgroup of $G$ of order $2$, and hence a unique (up to isomorphism) extension
$$\xi_1 : \mathbb Z/2\to \mathbb Z/2\times \mathbb Z/2\to \mathbb Z/2.$$
Thus $H^2(\mathbb Z/2,\mathbb Z/2) = \mathbb Z/2$, where the non-trivial element corresponds to the extension with middle term $\mathbb Z/4$, which is of course not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\times \mathbb Z/2$.
Note. For $G=\mathbb Z/p$, there are only two groups that fit into a sequence ending and starting at $G$, but there are $p$ equivalence classes of extension of $G$ by $G$. This has to do with the fact that one can embed $G$ in $\mathbb Z/p^2$ in $p-1$ different ways by multiplying by $i = 1, \ldots, p-1$, giving non-equivalent extensions, but isomorphic middle term. So, the size of the cohomology group does not necessarily inform on the number of isomorphism classes of middle terms.
